# Include GCM Push Notification into my app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to the user when a task is assigned (i.e on a button click). When a task is assigned to the user I change some values in my server(i.e i'm performing a post method) I would like to know how to achieve this.
I have reached till registering the user when he logs in to my app & i'm storing users token id into my server I have also gone through google developers guide and have registered my app and obtained senderid and serverapikey. I will post the code till where I have reached please help me on how to proceed further.

LoginActivity

```
 private void checkUserRegistrationToken() {
    String url = URLMap.getGcmtokenUrl("gcmtoken_url");
    employeeId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInEmployeeId(getApplicationContext());
    companyId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInCompanyId(getApplicationContext());
    url = url.replace("{eid}", employeeId).replace("{cid}", companyId);
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                tokenId = jObj.getString("TokenId");
                if (tokenId.equals("null")) {
                    registerInBackground();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error===" + error.toString());
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new VolleyRetryPolicy().getRetryPolicy());
    RequestQueue queue = ((VolleyRequestQueue) getApplication()).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(request);
}

private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcmObj == null) {
                    gcmObj = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(LoginActivity.this);
                }
                tokenId = gcmObj.register(String.valueOf(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId));
                msg = "Registration ID:" + tokenId;
                if (new ServiceManager(getApplicationContext()).isNetworkAvailable() && checkPlayServices()) {
                    String storeUrl = URLMap.getGcmtokenPostUrl();
                    employeeId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInEmployeeId(getApplicationContext());
                    companyId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInCompanyId(getApplicationContext());
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("EmployeeId", employeeId);
                    map.put("CompanyId", companyId);
                    map.put("TokenId", tokenId);
                    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, storeUrl, new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Token has been posted in server!");
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Error posting token into server!!");
                        }
                    });
                    request.setRetryPolicy(new VolleyRetryPolicy().getRetryPolicy());
                    RequestQueue queue = ((VolleyRequestQueue) getApplication()).getRequestQueue();
                    queue.add(request);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Token Mesage=" + msg);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

As you can see that I'm storing token id of user into my server.
Now I have also created a GcmBroadcastReceiver class

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            NotificationService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

and I have also created a NotificationService class which has on MessageReceived method

```
public class NotificationService extends GcmListenerService {


public static final int notifyID = 9001;
public static final String appname = "FM Ninja";
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public NotificationService() {
    //    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        Intent resultIntent = null;
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
        resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setTicker("New Message !")
                .setContentText("first message please")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.cms_launch_icon);

        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

}

The problem is even after adding permission in Manifeast when a call is made from server onMessageReceived is never getting executed Please help me.
I will also post manifeast file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--GCM Permissions-->

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<permission android:name="com.six30labs.cms.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.six30labs.cms.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:name="com.six30labs.cms.general.VolleyRequestQueue"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/cms_launch_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" />
    <activity android:name=".NoInternet" />
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ComplaintDetailsSupervisor" />
    <activity android:name=".ComplaintDetailsEmployee" />
    <activity android:name=".NavBarProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".ComplaintDetailsWorker" />
    <activity android:name=".AssignedDetailSupervisor" />
    <activity android:name=".AcceptedComplaintDetailsWorker" />
    <activity android:name=".VerifyDetailSupervisor"/>
    <activity android:name=".ManagerComplaintListActivity"/>

    <!--<service android:name="com.six30labs.cms.storage.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>-->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.six30labs.cms.general.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.six30labs.cms"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Register Service -->

    <service android:name="com.six30labs.cms.general.NotificationService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Server side script

```
public class GCMNotification
{
    private CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities();
    static string gcmid = "AIzaSyB7HSIF1RIvkyCnpP6KtYiy6wQ-s6YBscY";

    public void AssignEmpNotification(string employeeid)
    {
        long id = Convert.ToInt64(employeeid);
        PushBroker pushBroker = new PushBroker();
        pushBroker.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(gcmid));
        pushBroker.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId("APA91bGElkVodLyubuMM90TEnfUMab0Fs6JudsjXcgIUrTrT8Zk3GezKYWc9w2gGs6pzLLq_nPSZCXU30M5iYKdRJcKZnkafWuwhnihZQ88vcwUrKhiQn6eWSqGrLCeHFblVT09IR7jy")
           .WithJson(@"{""message"":""Hi Hello" + "wsfdasd" + @""",""title"":""title" + "vendorBids" + @""",""Bidsid"":""" + "1" + @""",""Eventdate"":""" + "2/2/2016" + @""",""vendorname"":""" + "name" + @"""}"));

        pushBroker.StopAllServices();
    }

}
```

Comment: I just want to hard code token id and receive a notification to my mobile once I achieve that than I will code when the notification has to be sent on server side.

Comment: post your server side code as that will be responsible for sending the gcm through google cloud.

Comment: Sir, We are using GCMNotification.cs...

Answer (score 1):

1. The server needs to send http post request 
   to "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" along with list of 
   registration ids and message as body data.

   The body data is a combination of :
      a. registration ids (which is a list of array)
      b. message

   The header is a combination of :
      a. Content-Type
      b. Authorization (key:project id)

   2. List regIds = new ArrayList();
      //add regIds to this list : regIds.add("value");
      JSONObject data = new JSONObject ();
      data.put("registration_ids", regIds);
      data.put("Message", "Hello");
   3. ApiKey  is the value we received during project created in google store.
      Map headers = new HashMap();
      headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
      header.put("Authorization","key=ApiKey");
   4. After sending http post request. The google gcm server will send 
      the message to all users whose registration id is mentioned in http
      request.
   5. The android mobile will receive a notification from gcm server as response 
      which will be handled by GCMBroadcastReceiver.
      Now NotificationService class will be invoked which will extent
      IntentService.
      In this class , 
      @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
      String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

      if (!extras.isEmpty() &&
      GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
          showNotification(intent.getStringExtra("Message"));
      }
      GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
      }
   6. This method is calling "showNotification" method which has a string
      parameter.
      Use this message and show in notification using NotificationManager.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can I get a confirmation whether GCM Server has received the message sent from my server?
I'm getting a Success output in my server but I doubt if it is received by GCM server...

Comment: If  response has success, failure, results. This means server responded back to the request. The success column tells how many ids received message and failure tells how many could not. Could you please paste the response from GCMServer. To check more a curl request can be used to send GCMNotification.

Comment: From command prompt use curl request as :   curl --header "Authorization:key=API_KEY" --header Content Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"data\" : {\"Message\":\"Welcome to push notifications\"} \"registration_ids\":[\"regId\"] }"

Comment: Hello Sir,
I tried logging the response but the response from server is getting failed it is giving as [GCM mismatchSenderId] even though I'm using proper sender id and I have also tried re-creating another project on google developer console and registered my mobile and obtained a new key[token] but still it shows same error message.. Please help
Regards,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Start logging the response that the server is getting after sending the notification payload to google servers. If there is a problem with the device token, you will get a detailed error like "Not Registered".

If the there is no problem in token, google server will respond you with success and message id.

Once you are assured that there is no problem with the device token, then we can think about the issues in the device code.

Other probable issue I can think of is that the SHA hash that you have  added in the google developer console is not matching with the SHA hash of the keystore that you have signed the app with. 
Add the SHA hash of debug.keystore as well as the production signing keystore.

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried logging the response but the response from server is getting failed it is giving as [GCM mismatchSenderId] even though I'm using proper sender id and I have also tried re-creating another project on google developer console and registered my mobile and obtained a new key[token] but still it shows same error message.. Please help Regards, Rakesh